# Is there a better way to filter an associative array?

Tags: php

Trying to sort my array to show the group with meat categoryName to be first element in array. Is there a better way to sort this array than running two for loops?
My array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [categoryId] => C4ye95zr403cx9wqi11eo
            [categoryName] => set
            [categoryStatus] => true
        )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [categoryId] => Cj-v2b7szu3jpph1rvu03
            [categoryName] => meat
            [categoryStatus] => true
        )
```

I want to rearrange the array by categoryName == meat to be first element in array.

Currently i'm just running two loops to do this.

```
$temp = array();
foreach($array as $k => $v)
            {
                if($v['categoryName']=="meat")
                {
                    $temp[]     = $menu[$k];
                    $setEmpty   = false;
                    unset($array[$k]);
                }
            }
            foreach($menu as $k=>$v)
            {
                $temp[] = $array[$k];
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort):

```
usort($array, function ($element) {
    return $element['categoryName'] === 'meat' ? 0 : 1;
});
```

The documentation states the following about the callback:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

So, in order to push the `meat` category to the beginning, all you need to do is say that everything else is greater than it.

You can check the [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/Vstk3) for a test.