# Sort an associative/multidimensional array based on a sub-object array value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking to sort an associative array ($rows) based on a sub-object array value. The array consists of products, and some of them has a "badge". These can be a campaign badge, and I would like to sort them, so they are displayed first.

I've searched, but couldn't find a solution I could use. This is beyond my skill level.

In pseudocode I'm looking to do the following:

```
IF $row->badges is array // product has a badge

AND $row->badges[$i]->badge_name == 'campaign' // product has the right badge

THEN sort array so all campaign products are displayed first, ordered by product_name
```

Example of my array:

```
Array (
[0] =&gt; stdClass Object
    (
        [product_id] =&gt; 195
        [product_name] =&gt; Product name
        [badges] =&gt; Array
            (
                [0] =&gt; stdClass Object
                    (
                        [badge_id] =&gt; 3
                        [badge_name] =&gt; NAME TO SORT ON
                        [badge_published] =&gt; 1
                        [badge_access] =&gt; all
                    )

            )

    )

[1] = ...
[2] = ...
[3] = ...
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64957183/is-there-a-better-way-to-filter-an-associative-array/) concerns associative arrays, not an array of objects, but the principle is the same.

Comment: @El_Vanja thanks, that answer helped getting me in the right direction. 

This almost works. Problems is, some products has multiple badges, and I need to check each badge. Current code only looks at the first badge. 

usort($this->rows, function ($element) {return $element->badges[0]->badge_name === 'Nyhed' ? 0 : 1;});

Comment: ^ `usort()` is the right way to go here. Could you add an **Update** section in your question with the code you are trying?

Comment: Although the code needs to be in the question itself, consider using something like [this code runner](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/), so readers can help you find your buglet.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic, we need to sort the array by badge condition and within the campaign badge group we need to sort by a product name. Please take a look at the following snippet.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

$campaignBadge                  = new \stdClass();
$campaignBadge->badge_id        = 3;
$campaignBadge->badge_name      = 'campaign';
$campaignBadge->badge_published = 1;
$campaignBadge->badge_access    = 'all';

$whateverBadge                  = new \stdClass();
$whateverBadge->badge_id        = 5;
$whateverBadge->badge_name      = 'whatever';
$whateverBadge->badge_published = 1;
$whateverBadge->badge_access    = 'all';

$product1               = new \stdClass();
$product1->product_id   = 195;
$product1->product_name = 'Product name 1';
$product1->badges       = [
    $campaignBadge,
];

$product2               = new \stdClass();
$product2->product_id   = 290;
$product2->product_name = 'Amazing product';
$product2->badges       = [
    $whateverBadge,
];

$product3               = new \stdClass();
$product3->product_id   = 102;
$product3->product_name = 'Some product';
$product3->badges       = [
    $whateverBadge,
];

$product4               = new \stdClass();
$product4->product_id   = 250;
$product4->product_name = 'Awesome product';
$product4->badges       = [
    $campaignBadge,
];

$products = [
    $product1,
    $product2,
    $product3,
    $product4,
];

usort($products, static function ($a, $b) {
    $aHasCampaignBadge = false;
    foreach ($a->badges as $badge) {
        if ('campaign' === $badge->badge_name) {
            $aHasCampaignBadge = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    $bHasCampaignBadge = false;
    foreach ($b->badges as $badge) {
        if ('campaign' === $badge->badge_name) {
            $bHasCampaignBadge = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$aHasCampaignBadge && !$bHasCampaignBadge) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ($aHasCampaignBadge && $bHasCampaignBadge) {
        return strcmp($a->product_name, $b->product_name);
    }

    return $aHasCampaignBadge < $bHasCampaignBadge;
});

var_dump($products);
```